# Is Amanaki Town a no-fly zone?

Tags: far-cry-3

Just now, I decided to see if I could fly from Cradle Gas to Dr. Eberhardt's mansion. I got in the glider located at X:654.9 Y:694.0, waypointed the mansion so I'd have something to aim at, and hurled myself into the wild blue yonder.

Everything was going swimmingly (over 2km of travel!) when suddenly my flight path took me over Amanaki Town and faster then you can say 'Bermuda Triangle' my glider plummeted out of the sky and crashed.

This has happened to me once before when I tried to use a glider to bypass the 'infiltrate the ship' mission, but I can't understand why the Amanaki wouldn't want me flying over their village.

**Can gliders be flown over Amanaki Town or will they always crash?**

Extra Credit: **If so, what other no-fly zones always exist on Rook Island (as opposed to per-mission no-fly zones)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have noticed that there are certain areas of the game-world in which Jason puts aside his weapon. Those are all no-fly zones. (Assuming they are under the open sky. Citras temple would be another example)

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is yes, it is a no fly zone. I had the same experience as you in the "infiltrate the ship" mission, and amanaki is the same.